# How to wire three 10W LED spotlights to one plug?

Tags: led, connector, wiring

I have 3 10W LED spotlights that I want to attach to a wooden canopy to light my fishtank. They have live, neutral and ground. They look like this:

[image]

It requires AC 85-265V. I could easily attach each one to a three-point plug but that would look messy and I would need three plug-points.

I was wondering if it would be dangerous to instead wire all three of them using an electrical connection block and then use a single cable+plug like this?

[image]

I know the cable would need to be able to withstand the current needed by all three lights but I don't know how many amps it would pull (complete amateur). I have an extension cord that I would like to use the wire from, I assume this would be good enough since it has a bunch of plug-points and therefore can withstand the current?

Also, would wiring it like this affect the brightness at all?

Comment: Correct. Your brightness is not affected. They will pull about 0.15 A.

Comment: Great, so would wiring it like this be safe and acceptable?

Comment: 10 Watts x3? Not enough current to worry about, as Winny says. Connector block's fine, keep it behind an insulating cover (i.e. built into the woodwork or a plastic connection box) and well away from moisture.

Comment: Whilst you're at it, check that all of the spotlights have the earth correctly connected - some of them don't.

Comment: @BenjaminWharton Thanks! I did notice none of them were grounded AT ALL inside! I ended up adding a ground wire. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that would work.

Use a 3A fuse, unless those lights have a terrible efficiency your power draw will be less than 1/4A. There will be no issues with the cables ability to handle the current.

No it won't have any effect on brightness.

That said I would advice against your plan. This is almost certainly against any electrical safety codes, they would require 3 separate plugs.
That terminal block is going to have 220V on it and most terminal blocks aren't designed to be safe if left laying around where people can reach.

Assuming the cables aren't too thick it would be safer to wire all three directly into the same plug. 
Failing that at the very least ensure that the terminal block is one of the ones inside a housing to prevent any accidental contact with the live connections.

Comment: awesome. Thanks for the answer, much appreciated :)